# Contact form or mailto for Portfolio?

Tags: forms, portfolio, contact-us

I'm currently thinking about my portfolio design and I would like some advices from experts. For a personal and professional portfolio, is it better to have a contact form or a mailto? This is my choice bellow:

1. Build Simple contact form with great design.
2. Under my biography/about me a section, have a button showing "Contact me" and when you hover on, it show my contact email and if you click on it you have the mailto in action. The only thing is that I'm not sure you can copy/paste text appearing on hover, so it will not work with people without mail client.
3. Just my contact email and when you click on it you have mailto bellow about me section, at the bottom of the page or in the footer.

I know that many people created the same topic before, but maybe it changed since then.

Thanks

Comment: Might want to look at this question: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/6959/contact-form-or-mailto-link?rq=1

Comment: Why Mailto Links Should Be Avoided On Websites https://blog.seibert-media.com/2014/10/06/why-mailto-links-should-be-avoided-on-websites/